# How Do I Make my Screen Scrollable in Android Eclipse

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

This is the **XML** code I have before I attempt to adjust it to be scrollable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!-- all my widgets -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

How do I edit this to make it scrollable? Dragging on a `ScrollView` from the widget list just messes everything up.

Comment: i am not downvoting..

Comment: @753 It doesn't look to me like you've accepted any answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you leave the `version/encoding` line at the very top of your file.

Change `RelativeLayout` to `ScrollView` and then nest a `RelativeLayout` section (containing all of your widgets) inside that new `ScrollView`.

Make sure you give the `RelativeLayout` some dimensions, which should be the same as the `ScrollView` *width* and *height* dimensions.

The reason for this nesting of the `RelativeLayout` that contains all the widgets is that a `ScrollView` element can only have one child element (in this case, the `RelativeLayout`, which then has its own children).

Therefore this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- all your widgets -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Turns into this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >      

        <!-- all your widgets -->

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```