# ScrollView with 2 Buttons which are fixed at the bottom

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I just know how to fix two buttons at the bottom of RelativeLayout. But the problem is that small displays can not see everything, so I want to have a scrollLayout but also a Relative Layout so the two buttons are at the bottom of the display every time. Does anyone have an idea how to implement it?
Thanks very much :)

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864595/how-do-i-make-my-screen-scrollable-in-android-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
  <LinearLayout>
        <ScrollLayout>
            <RelativeLayout>
                Your content here
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollLayout>
        <RelativeLayout>
            Your two buttons here
        </RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```