# xml layout isn't working for me

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a lot of info to put on one xml page. Now i got what I want in the positions i want. However instead of fitting all my data on 3 key parts  without running into each other, It keeps running into the next TextView. I was wondering how to have it auto adjust.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/back_button"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:text="@string/back" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/makeup_title"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/info_title"
          android:layout_marginTop="97dp"
          android:text="@string/part_section_2" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/part_info"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/info_title"
          android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
          android:text="put text here for info" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/part_safety"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/part_makeup"
          android:layout_below="@+id/safety_title"
          android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
          android:text="put text here for safety" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/info_title"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
          android:text="@string/part_section_1" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/part_makeup"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/part_info"
          android:layout_below="@+id/makeup_title"
          android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
          android:text="put text here for makeup" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/safety_title"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/part_makeup"
          android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
          android:text="@string/part_section_3" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/part_title"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
          android:textColor="#b70000"
          android:textSize="16sp"
          android:text="put text here for part title" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

would ScrollView work better? and how would switch this from this to ScrollView.
[image]

skin is 480x800 
density is high(240)

Strings file - http://pastie.org/8534713

Comment: Tell me if my answer works for you. It's what I do to make my layouts scrollview. Some stuff *might* be disaligned from normal depending on the properties. You have to toy around with it.

Comment: What size screen are you looking at it on in your graphical layout? Just so I can test it myself. Also, can you please post your `Strings.xml` file to http://pastie.org and send me the link so I can use your strings too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to ScrollView ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864595/how-do-i-make-my-screen-scrollable-in-android-eclipse)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!-- your Button and TextView widgets -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

---

**Edit**:

As well as that, try changing your back button XML to this:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/back_button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/part_safety"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
     android:text="@string/back" />
```

The problem was `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. The bottom ended up not going to the bottom of the page like you had before. The ScrollView cut back on the bottom of the layout.

Comment: the button was moved in the process. I don't know why.

Comment: @HankBates everything is relative to one another in XML. So if you create a ScrollView instead of a RelativeLayout, things are relative to it in different ways. For example: aligning it center vertical might be different for the ScrollView than the RelativeLayout because the centers are in different spots. Play around with it; make it relative to something else but still in the same spot. Try stuff out.

Comment: oh i got the button moved around, but it is still running into the other TextViews.

Comment: i added this to my main question... how did it appear here

Comment: Yaworki Just did it all in the edit, The pic should show what prob i am having.

Comment: @HankBates try my updated edit and tell me if you still have problems.

Comment: @Micke Yaworski Yes but in a different way now. some of my TextViews are switched around.

Comment: @HankBates mine doesn't look the same as yours. I'd say you're on your own for now. If you get it working, please accept and vote up my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Its cool thanks man. I going to use what you showed me. Thanks for the info.